# Using Spring Boot's ENV variables from JHipster App

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `JhiConfigurationService` from JHipster Angular App. I've managed to access the env variables using this service from the App after injecting the service into my Angular component but it only works if I'm logged in as an "admin" user. As soon as I switch to the normal user, the service won't return any values. I've found that there is an endpoint configuration for Spring Boot but in the existing `application.yml` configs there is nothing which would change the default behavior (sanitizing specific keywords).

**Edit**: I thought that there might be a way of telling spring which ENV variables it should allow to read without ADMIN role. Similar to `endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize` from [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: I gave negative score, because you do not explain how you successfully read application.yml from angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit `configure()` method in `SecurityConfiguration.java` so that `/management/env` does not require ADMIN authority (order matters) but **be careful to expose only safe data**.

```
.antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/management/env").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
```

Comment: Sorry but maybe I didn't express myself clear enough. Of course I don't want to expose all the ENV variables... I thought that there might be a way of telling spring with some pattern which ENV variables it should allow to read without ADMIN role. Similar to endpoints.env.keys-to-sanitize= from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Personally, I would just write my own resource controller as we did for exposing spring profile in ProfileInfoResource.java