# Configuration values from application.yml in angularjs jHipster

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, configuration, config, jhipster

I am new to jhipster and i am not really sure how to read configuration values in angularjs from application.yml file in jhipster, I need to define a value in application.yml file and get that value in angularjs and use it, is this possible in jhipster, can you please let me know how will this work?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add some codes please.

Comment: To be frank nothing, i am stuck i do not know where to start to do this, the only idea i came up with was putting the config value inside database and read it through an api which is k for me as this value is not required to start the application but it would be really good if i put this config value inside application.yml

Comment: I dont't see why you should use the application.yml for angular. Use angular config for angular :-)

Comment: But i wont be able to change the configuration after deploying it right? or will I be able to?

Comment: no you won't. You can add a rest end point for that configuration

Comment: Can i achieve this through webconfigurer class?

Comment: WebConfigurer is used to configure your web mvc layer, it has nothing to do with what Torsten suggested. You can find an example of endpoint exposing some application properties in ProfileInfoResource.java. Also I recommend that you learn more about Spring Boot.

Comment: You should see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43620898/using-spring-boots-env-variables-from-jhipster-app/

Comment: Cool, Thanks, this is what i was looking for, worked, and i need this option only for an admin account so, the solution is perfect, thank you.